# How can I fix my code to properly display my menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code has no red flags in it. It runs but it doesnt display anything?

```
def main():
  menuInput()

def menu():
  print('''
  Welcome! Please make a choice from the following menu

  1. Select a year and display available data
  2. Review averages by year range
  3. Select a date range and show highest temperature
  4. Select a date range and show lowest temperature 
  5. Get total rainfall for a selected year range
  6. blank
  7. blank
  8. See this menu again
  9. QUIT the program
''')


def menuInput():
  while True:
    menu()
    try:
      userChoice=int(input('Please make a selection: '))
      if userChoice > 9:
        print('Please enter a number less or equal to 9')
      elif userChoice <= 0:
            print('Please enter a number greater than 0')
      elif userChoice == 1:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 2:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 3:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 4:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 5:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 6:
            print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 7:
            print('Invalid Choice')
      elif userChoice == 8:
        print('Good')
      elif userChoice == 9:
        print('Program Exiting!')
      else:
        print('Invalid Choice')
        continue
    except ValueError:
      print('Please enter a whole number instead')
      continue
  main()
```

I would like to assume it is because menu() either hasnt been called properly or has not been assigned a to a variable like displayMenu=*MENU CODE*. Im not sure how to properly go about adding or passing that variable without ruining it

Comment: There is no function call outside of a function. Probably wrong indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have copied and pasted the code verbatim, then the issue is that your `main()` function is indented improperly. Unindent the line `main()`.

When you indent `main()`, it becomes part of the function `menuInput()`, and as a result nothing is run in the **actual** `main` of Python (`if __name__ == "__main__")`.